# php-google-spreadsheet-client getSpreadsheets returning empty array

Tags: php, google-sheets-api

I'm using the [php-google-spreadsheet-client](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client) to get the list of google sheets. Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    require_once 'google-api-php-client/autoload.php';

    use Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest;
    use Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory;

    function getToken()
    {
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setApplicationName('project');
        $client->setClientId('client_id');

        $key = file_get_contents('key.p12');
        $cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
            'id@developer.gserviceaccount.com',
            array('https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds'),
            $key
        );

        $client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

        if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
            $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
        }

        $service_token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
        return $service_token->access_token;
    }

    $accessToken = getToken();
    $serviceRequest = new DefaultServiceRequest($accessToken);
    ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);
    $spreadsheetService = new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService();
    $spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheets();
    print_r(count($spreadsheetFeed));
    foreach($spreadsheetFeed as $spreadsheet){
        print_r($spreadsheet);
    }
```

But the getSpreadsheets() function is returning an empty array.
How can I get the list of my google sheets?

Comment: What line is the error on?

Comment: @SandyGood There are no errors. But I managed to fix it. I didn't know that I had to share the sheets with the client email inorder to get it. Just waiting to see if some will post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know what the answer is.  You need to share the sheets with the client email in order to get it.